# router express, a route return "Cannot GET", for no apparent reason

Tags: node.js, express

Here is a bug, that we could call stupid, that I had recently and that I just solved. I'm posting this here in case some people have the same problem.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// define the home page route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('agent home page');
});


// define the about route
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({test:"test"});
});

router.get("/list ", function(req, res)  {
      try {
    res.status(200).json({test:"test list"});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Unexpected error : " + err });
  }
});
```

the first two requests come from the express site and work very well.
https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html

The third one is the one I was planning to build.

In your opinion, why does the third request not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's the space between the quotation mark and the word list.

correction:

```
router.get("/list", function(req, res)  {
```

In short, if you have a query that you just wrote or copied/pasted that doesn't work, check to see if there's an objectionable space, it could save you time.